# Program does not terminate when called from udev

Tags: ubuntu, gentoo, udev, mono

I've written a program in C#/Mono that probes a device to determine if it is a modem.

The program works fine from the command line. However, when it is called from `PROGRAM=` in a udev rule, the program runs properly until the end, and then fails to terminate. As an additional piece of information, the program *does* terminate when called from `RUN+=`.

The program also terminates successfully, even when called from `PROGRAM=`, on a different system based on Ubuntu. The system in question here is running Gentoo.

Additionally, a one line "Hello world" application written in C# has the same symptoms as my application.

What could cause the program not to terminate?

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question. The program fails to terminate because there's a bug. If you want specific help, reduce your program to a short snippet that exhibits the problem and ask on [so]. As a general debugging tip, try running the program under `strace` and compare a working run with a non-working run; this will show where the behaviors diverge if the program is reacting differently to different external events. If the problem is an issue inside the program such as an internal race condition, you'll have to add debugging traces or use a debugger.

Comment: Gilles: A "hello world" C# program has the exact same behavior as my application; it isn't a bug in my code.

Comment: Ah, then it's a different matter. What if the program doesn't print anything? Can you reproduce this with a non-C# program? What precise versions of the C# compiler and runtime environment are you using? What does strace show?

Comment: Gilles: No dice with a non-printing program too. And no, its definitely a Mono issue, but I'd need to narrow down the environmental cause before I could report it. gdb makes it seem like its waiting on a semaphore; strace shows the exact same output except that when udev calls it, it has less in the trace (ends earlier). Both the Ubuntu and the Gentoo system are running on 2.10.2-r1 of Mono.

Comment: (This was tested on 2.10.5 in Gentoo, but it worked on 2.10.2-r1 on Ubuntu so I downgraded Mono on Gentoo in order to sync up.)